# Windows 10 clean install

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

Using a computer with a brand new empty hard drive, it is possible to do a clean
install of Windows 10 full edition?

In this case assume I have no other versions of Windows, am not interested in
any upgrades from previous versions of Windows, am not concerned with extra cost
associated with full version.

With all previous versions of Windows, namely Windows 7, you could purchase a
full version and install and activate it on a new hard drive. I want to make
sure this is still possible with Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [purchase](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-10-Home/productID.319937100) Windows 10 outright. You can download it or have a flash drive sent to you.

Answer (score 2):

you can download an iso from the [MSDN Subscriber Downloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=606&Languages=en&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=100&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) and install a clean Windows 10 with said iso.

Comment: do you have to pay to initate the download, or only to enter the license *post* install?

Answer (score 0):

windows 10 is available to purchase on sites such as amazon on either a flash drive or cd with the installation media on. The price is the same regardless of the method used. The only difference in price is between versions (home and pro).

Comment: how do you know whether you're buing a legit product?  Not already infected?  Or pirated?